Why did they not give the Kohen Godol longer to practice the difficult ketores service?
Mishnah Yoma 1 (5) says that on Erev Yom Kippur, the Elders of the priesthood took the Kohen Godol up to the House of Avtinas. After administering an oath to the Kohen Godol, the Elders  instructed him in the difficult process of the ketores offering, as the Yachin says:

ילמדוהו ז‏קני כהונה, חפינת הקטורת, דעבודה קשה היתה:

Why did they not instruct him before that to give him more time to perfect this difficult avodah?

I am answering the OP with my own answer as it seems to me to be obvious from the texts of Torah and our Sages concerning the subject matter of Yom Kippur and the High Priest's Service on Yom Kippur.
Specifically, The Torah says the High Priest must pour his (2) handfulls of incense spices onto the burning coals in the Holy of Holies. Leviticus 16: 12-13

And he shall take a pan full of burning coals from upon the altar, from before the L-rd, and both hands' full of fine incense, and bring [it] within the dividing curtain. And he shall place the incense upon the fire, before the L-rd, so that the cloud of the incense shall envelope the ark cover that is over the [tablets of] Testimony, so that he shall not die.

The Talmud explains that the High Priest must pour the incense from a special spoon into his hands and from the hands onto the coals etc. The physical juggling of the spoon tilting into his two hands and then onto the coals in a way that he doesn't lose a grain of incense in the process is called "Chafinah" and is one of the most difficult of services to perform properly in the temple. (See Yoma 47b at the top of the page)("Some say he holds the bowl/spoon with his fingertips, some say with is teeth etc." See Yoma 49b, also at the top of the page.)
So this was a difficult task and needed practice. The OP asks why the High Priest apparently waited until the last day before Yom Kippur to practice it?
List of Facts When taken together that help answer the question:

Although the Mishnah deals with all time periods; but it is set in the time during the second Temple era, when the office of High Priest was usually filled by people who bid the highest amount to the King or Romans. Many were not neccesarily worthy of the position (even not-so-religious or of the Saducees etc.), but simply bought there way in so they could experience the honor and greatness of being the High Priest on Yom Kippur.

The Torah requires that the commandment of the High Priest pouring his "two handfuls" of incense be exactly two handfuls and be exactly two handfuls of that particular High Priest's hands doing the service. Therefore the amount of incense used is unknown until we can examine the hands of the High Priest himself. This is an integral part of the difficult "Chafinah Service" (pouring the incense on the coals in the Holy of Holies) which the OP is focusing on.

Another important fact is that the Temple would therefore manufacture a special container with a handle that held exactly the amount of incense to be used by that High Priest based on his hands' capacity. Therefore a custom utensil was made for the specific High Priest each year (certainly for different High Priests).

The Law is that the Yom Kippur incense was different in physical quality and density, only on the day before Yom Kippur. This is because on the day before Yom Kippur, the incense prepared the whole year was returned to the grinder and re-pounded until it was the "finest of the finest" in texture.

The High Priest was only sequestered to live at the Temple 7 days before the day of Yom Kippur.


Sources:

The Gemara says that that in the first Temple (stood for 410 years), only 18 high Priests served but during the second Temple over 300 High Priests served (stood for 420 years). This is because the average high Priest did not last the year because he bought his office and was not worthy. Some were wicked or Sadducees. Others were completely unlearned and did not know Hebrew since they could only understand Scripture in Aramaic like the Book of Daniel. (See Yoma 9a; Yoma 18a - 19b sporadically at length)

2-3. The commandment of "Chafinah" required the High Priests exact 2 handfulls and the custom spoon/ladle. see Yoma (47a; Mishnah 1 etc.)

The incense was repounded again erev Yom Kippur. (See Kerisos 6a-b; Jerusalem Talmud Yoma 4:5)

The High Priest lived at the Temple sequestered for the 7 days before Yom Kippur. (See Yoma 1:1)


Once we know this we can answer the OP.
(First the Gemara on 19a seems to quote a Baraisa that implies the High Priest would go learn the "Chafinah" service every day of the 7 days. Indeed the Gemara claims that walking too much (each day) to find his way to the incense room to tire him out, was so he would quit from laziness if he was a Sadducee. Therefore it seems like he visited the incense chamber for all 7 days to learn and practice. If not, why did one day of practice tire him out?. However as the OP points out, the Yachin's commentary seems to indicate it was only on the day before Yom Kippur and only after the oath was administered.)
So wether you hold he practiced 7 days or 1 day, you can still ask why not practice way before for 30 days or a couple of months?
As we saw, many High Priests bought their office and were not interested in mastering the finer aspects of religious service. Therefore, the Sages and regular Priests didn't get to train the candidate until 7 days before Yom Kippur (when they bought their office).
Secondly, because the incense had to be the exact amount of that High Priest's two hands volume, the spoon couldn't be manufactured until we met the winning bidder.
Furthermore, since the incense was re-pounded freshly, only on the day before Yom Kippur, its consistency would change. Therefore, I say the Yachin's explanation is vindicated because the Temple could not manufacture the spoon/ladle for that particular High Priest to practice with, until the day before Yom Kippur, so we would know how much finer and how dense the incense would be, so it could fit exactly into his custom made vessel!
Again, just my conclusion. I hope this helps.
